# Customizing bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, bibliographystyle

In the requirements of The Lancet Journal, there are instructions on the bibliography settings :

Here is an example for a journal reference (note the use of tab,
bold, italic, and the en rule or “long” hyphen):
“15[tab]Saito N, Ebara S, Ohotsuka K, Kumeta
J, Takaoka K. Natural history of scoliosis in spastic
cerebral palsy. Lancet 1998; **351**: 1687–[en rule]92.”

I had been using natbib up to this point but I could not find how to customize the bibliography with this package. I found on similar questions that I should tweek the .bst files but I have never used these functionnalities of Latex.

Should I switch the package I am using ? What should I use ? and how can I modify the bst file to define the appropriate emphasis and separation between items of the bibliography ?

Comment: It's generally easier to patch `biblatex` commands, as it uses latex commands.

Comment: Sorry I am not very experienced with Latex, what do you mean by patch biblatex commands ?

Comment: If this is for submission to the Lancet, double check if they (1) accept LaTeX submissions and (2) if the can accept `biblatex` in a LaTeX submission, before you go down the `biblatex` route. Many journals that accept TeX submissions have their own templates that are generally incompatible with `biblatex` and its workflow.

Comment: Based on https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions I assumed that all Elsevier journals accepted Latex submissions, but I may be wrong...

Comment: @endive1783: I meant modifying some parts of the code to obtain what you want, which can easily be done with the help of a package like `xpatch`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks I will look that up